# Problem with android:targetSdkVersion attribute

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdcard

I have an application compiled in Android 1.6 (api level 4) but I need to add `android:installLocation` attribute. I have put this line in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

I have defined the `android:targetSdkVersion` as 8, but the `android:installLocation` doesn't work right.

Comment: Are you compiling your application with Android tools for API 8? Check your default.properties file.

Comment: I'm compiling my application for API level 4

Comment: So you need to compile it for the 8th level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile against the Level 8 SDK.

Look for point number 3 in the Backwards Compatibility section here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Comment: +1 ya @aromero is right just keep minSdk as 4 and built the code for 2.2 are as you like that's it done.. app can moved to sd card when you installed for it 2.2 and higher. also we can install it for lower version also.